# How to pass data to React components with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am completely new to the field which is why I might be having a silly question over here.

I have set up a react-redux app. All the redux boilerplate is ready and is functioning properly. Now, I am willing to add a feature that will take data from one React Component and pass it to another, while hiding it or deleting it from the first component.

My question is, should I set up new action and update my root reducer in order to do that or there is an easier way to do that?

This is my first component which I am willing to take data from by clicking the "Rent" button. Also, I want the data piece to temporarily disappear from this component and appear in the second one.

```
class Available extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getRentals();
    }

    onDeleteClick = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteRental(id);
    }


    render() {
        const { rentals } = this.props.rental
        return (
            <Container fluid>
                <h2>List of Available Bikes</h2>
                <ListGroup>
                    <TransitionGroup className="rental-list">
                        { rentals.map(({ _id, name, bikeType, price }) => (
                            <CSSTransition key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                                <ListGroupItem>
                                    {name} / {bikeType} / ${price} / per hour
                                    <Button
                                        className="remove-btn float-right"
                                        color="danger"
                                        size="sm"
                                        onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, _id)}
                                    >Delete</Button>
                                    <Button
                                        className="remove-btn float-right"
                                        color="primary"
                                        size="sm"
                                        onClick={this.onRentClick(this, _id)}
                                    >Rent</Button>
                                </ListGroupItem>
                            </CSSTransition>
                        ))}
                    </TransitionGroup>
                </ListGroup>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is the second component that I am willing to pass the data to. Also, I am willing to add a feature that will bring the data piece back to the first component when I click the "Cancel Rent" button.

```
class Rented extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getRentals();
    }

    render() {
        const { rentals } = this.props.rental
        return (
            <Container fluid>
                <h2>List of Rented Bikes</h2>
                <ListGroup>
                    <TransitionGroup className="rental-list">
                        { rentals.map(({ _id, name, bikeType, price }) => (
                            <CSSTransition key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                                <ListGroupItem>
                                    {name} / {bikeType} / ${price} / per hour
                                    <Button
                                        className="remove-btn float-right"
                                        color="danger"
                                        size="sm"
                                    >Cancel Rent</Button>
                                </ListGroupItem>
                            </CSSTransition>
                        ))}
                    </TransitionGroup>
                </ListGroup>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Please let me know what is the best solution here :)

Comment: If you definitely want to keep that data in your Redux store, then yes, you'll need to create an action and reducer to update the store. You'll want to do this if your "rent" and "cancel rent" handlers are updating database records or if you need that info to persist when the components are unmounted. If neither of those cases applies, you might consider just keeping track of the "rented" and "available" lists in the parent component state.

Comment: @shannon Thank you for the soonest response. I have followed your advice and I have created both a reducer and an action. Now, I am struggling with my "rent" and "cancel rent" handlers to update the database records. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Databases are way outside the scope of this question. You'll want to make an API call in your action before updating the redux store. If you have specific database-related questions, you can post a new question

Comment: @shannon Thank you very much for your attention and assistance. Have a great day.